# MySQL: use result from select in "update" and "where" fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables for images, now I like to pack all images in one table and reference it via foreign key fk_image:

Also:

```
Table1: ('id_system' , 'logo_image_raw', 'fk_image')
Table2: ('id_image', 'image_raw_data')
```

How can I copy/move logo_image_raw to Table's 2 'image_raw_data' and reflect its id_image in fk_image?

Answer (score 1):

Just do `INSERT...INTO SELECT`

```
INSERT  INTO table2 (id_image, image_raw_data)
SELECT  fk_image, logo_image_raw
FROM    table1
```

if the column `image_raw_data` is null but you have already `id_image`, you need to join the tables so you can get the specific image for each ID,

```
UPDATE  table2 b 
        INNER JOIN table1 a
           ON a.fk_image = b.id_image
SET     b.image_raw_data = a.logo_image_raw
```

Comment: Hi,the problem is not to insert images into Table2, but to reference the new entries in Table1. That is first copy/insert image blob into Table2, get the id_image, and than update fk_image in Table1

Comment: That would be ok if the table2 hadn't any records, which is no the case. That is inserting id_image can cause data loss in table2

Comment: if that's the case then how will you link or what is the relationship of the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

You Can Do Just like That ..

```
 INSERT INTO table2
 SELECT table1.fk_image, table1.logo_image_raw
 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.fk_image = table2.id_image
```

Comment: Hi,the problem is not to insert images into Table2, but to reference the new entries in Table1. That is first copy/insert image blob into Table2, get the id_image, and than update fk_image in Table1

Comment: That's means you have no any info into `fk_image` field ... After moving `logo_image_raw` field info to table2 ... Then you want to get those table2 `id_image` and update those info to table1 `fk_image` field. Am i right ?